# How to remove found :AnyVal required :Double in scala ?

Tags: scala, scala-collections, type-mismatch

I am traversing a `Scala Map` and I am getting `type mismatch` error in my code. Here is what I am trying to do.

```
private var cumulativeCapacity:Map[String , Double] = Map()
private var cumulativeDelay:Map[String ,Double] = Map()

cumulativeCapacity.keys.foreach { linkId =>
    val delay = cumulativeDelay.get(linkId).getOrElse(0)
    val capacity = cumulativeCapacity.get(linkId).getOrElse(0)
    val bin = largeset(capacity)
}
```

So the error is coming inside `val bin = largeset(capacity)` that, `capacity` should be double but found `AnyVal`. Provide me any solution or let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

The problem you are experiencing is due to the fact that you are providing an `Int` as a default value when the key is not found in your `Map`, instead of a `Double`. If you change `0` by `0.0` or `0D` it should work. i.e

```
cumulativeCapacity.keys.foreach { linkId =>
  val delay = cumulativeDelay.getOrElse(linkId, 0D)
  val capacity = cumulativeCapacity.getOrElse(linkId, 0D)
  val bin = largeset(capacity)
}
```